# invalid input syntax for integer: "9Na_(2)SO_(4)"

Tags: postgresql, insert

I'm trying to insert a alphanumeric value in a table:

```
INSERT INTO solution (solution, nextsolution) VALUES
    ('9Na_(2)SO_(4)', NULL), ('2Ni(OH)_(3)', (SELECT id FROM solution WHERE solution='9Na_(2)SO_(4)' & nextsolution=null));
```

solution is of type text and nextsolution is an integer. Unfortunately postgresql doesn't allow me to do the WHERE clause. It gives me the error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "9Na_(2)SO_(4)"
LINE 9: ...OH)_(3)', (SELECT id FROM solution WHERE solution='9Na_(2)SO...
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: what's the type of solution and nextsolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the statement in the where clause: `'9Na_(2)SO_(4)' & nextsolution=null` tries to do a `bitwise and` (`&`) operation on the string and this won't work (and probably isn't what you want anyway).

Looking at your query I think what you want is to first insert the value `'9Na_(2)SO_(4)'` and then the value `'2Ni(OH)_(3)'` with the id of the previous inserted row.

You need to do this as two statements and use a different syntax. This should do what you want:

```
INSERT INTO solution (solution, nextsolution) VALUES (
  '9Na_(2)SO_(4)', 
  NULL
);

INSERT INTO solution (solution, nextsolution) VALUES (
  '2Ni(OH)_(3)', 
  (SELECT id FROM solution WHERE solution='9Na_(2)SO_(4)' and nextsolution is null)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AND` instead of `&` to join your `WHERE` clause - an ampersand (`&`) is used for bitwise operations.